# Uncaught object- anonymous function Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, dependencies, firebase, factory, angularfire

OK I give up! I need some help on this one. I have spent a very long time reading all of the similar questions that have been asked on S/O, and nothing has been able to help my problem. 
I'm trying to add a factory to my angularFire application.

I am getting the 'Uncaught Object (anonymous function)' error - Through Chrome inspector I have ascertained more specific error information: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=ngLocale%22

here is my HTML Script information:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.18/angular.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/factories.js"></script>

<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.17/firebase.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.7.1/angularfire.min.js'></script>
```

here is my controller.js:

```
legalmvc.controller('FormCtrl','FBRetrieve', function FormCtrl($scope, $location, FBRetrieve, $firebase) {
    var url = 'https://legalcitator.firebaseio.com';
    var fireRef = new Firebase(url);



    $scope.addCase = function () {
        $scope.FireBaseCases = new Firebase('https://legalcitator.firebaseio.com/case');
        $scope.caseData = {};

        var newAuthor = $scope.newAuthor;
        var newJournal = $scope.newJournal;
        var newArticleName = $scope.newArticleName;
        var newYear = $scope.newYear;

        if (!newAuthor.length || !newArticleName.length || !newJournal.length || newYear === null ) {
            return;
        }
        newAuthor = $scope.newAuthor.trim();
        newJournal = $scope.newJournal.trim();
        newArticleName = $scope.newArticleName.trim();

        var newCaseRow = $scope.FireBaseCases.child(newAuthor);
        newCaseRow.set({
            type: 'Case',
            author: newAuthor,
            journal: newJournal,
            articleName: newArticleName,
            year: newYear   }
        );


        $scope.newAuthor = '';
        $scope.newJournal ='';
        $scope.newYear =null;
        $scope.newArticleName= '';

    };





});
```

here is my factory.js :

```
legalmvc.factory('FBRetrieve', function(type){

    var biblioRef = new Firebase('https://legalcitator.firebaseio.com/'+type);

    biblioRef.on('value', function(data) {
        if (data.val() === null) {
            return;
        }

        return data;


    });

});
```

and here is the app.js

```
var legalmvc = angular.module('legalmvc', ['FBRetrieve','ngRoute']);
```

Will be deeply, deeply grateful if someone could give me a hand, this thing is giving me an aneurysm!!

Sam

EDIT:

The problem was that i was trying to inject my factory 'FBRetrieve' and an external module. I removed this, and then the problem that I was facing was  in this code

```
legalmvc.factory('FBRetrieve', function(type){

var biblioRef = new Firebase('https://legalcitator.firebaseio.com/'+type);

.....
```

it seems that you cannot pass 'type' in as a parameter on factory function which will allow you to use this same function on different URLs. Can't say i understand exactly why.

Thanks guys!!

Comment: Could you update your question with the current code so I'll maybe be able to help you further ?

Comment: @zazou: `type` would be in this context the dependency you are trying to inject. angular does not know a dependency `type` if you did not declare it e.g. a factory with name `type`. Anyway what you most likely would like to do is define a function on your factory not inject a type dependency into your factory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imho the issue is in: `var legalmvc = angular.module('legalmvc', ['FBRetrieve','ngRoute']);` remove the `FBRetrieve`entry. It's not an external module it's your factory.

You most likely wanted to use:

```
var legalmvc = angular.module('legalmvc', ['firebase','ngRoute']);
```

And you should inject `$firebase` instead creating new objects `new Firebase`, the rationale behind this is explained here: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing

Comment: THANKS!as i mentioned to WB i have run into a different problem. it errors suggesting that FBRetrieve has not been correctly injected/defined. i changed my controller signature to to try and fix the problem :"legalmvc.controller('FormCtrl',["$scope","FBRetrieve", function ($scope, FBRetrieve){.." - any ideas? thanks ! i really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not inject your factory on the creation of your module as the factory is registered on the module it already knows it.

Correct me if I'm wrong but module declaration only accept injection of other modules.

So from your code you only have to remove the FBRetrieve injection from the module creation.
It becomes :

```
var legalmvc = angular.module('legalmvc', ['ngRoute']);
```

As your factory and your controller are on the same module, it will resolve it when creating your controller.

If your factory was on another module, then you would have :

```
var factoryModule = angular.module("factoryModule"); 
factoryModule.factory('FBRetrieve', function(type){ 
     ...
}

var legalmvc = angular.module('legalmvc',['factoryModule', 'ngRoute']);
legalmvc.controller('controller',['FBRetrieve', '$scope', 
   function(FBRetrieve, $scope){
       ...
}]);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Very helpful, thankyou very much! @Andreas.
    
Unfortunately I am getting a different error.  "https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/unpr?p0=typeProvider%20%3C-%20type%20%3C-%20FBRetrieve" 
     
the "Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: typeProvider <- type <- FBRetrieve".  This suggests that I "make sure the dependency is defined and spelled correctly. "

once again I am stuck as I feel that the factory has been correctly defined.
I changed my controller signature to look like this:

legalmvc.controller('FormCtrl',["$scope","FBRetrieve", function ($scope, FBRetrieve){
is this OK?